# Extracting links from adobe acrobat pro dc pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, automation, acrobat, rpa

I have tried PyPDF2 and pdfx for extracting links from acrobat pro dc pdf. I am unable to fetch any links. These two modules works fine for normal pdf. Is there any module or way to extract the links from acrobat pro dc pdf using python

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *acrobat pro dc pdf*? Maybe you should share an example for comparison.

Comment: In acrobat pro dc pdf , link has properties like thickness, color , box,etc. When i try to extract links using pypdf2, I am unable to find any of them in “Annots”. Can you help me suggest any good module that can extract link and its properties

Comment: I cannot suggest any module. If I had an example of the document type you describe, I could try and analyze it for any reason why it may be difficult to extract the links in question.

Comment: I cant post the document. The document is pdf but when opened using acrobat pro dc the links has various properties. If you can suggest any methods you use, I can try it

Comment: I'd analyze the internal structure and compare with ISO 32000-2.